# Accessing javascript array more than once

Tags: javascript, function

I have a simple function where I pass a name and age parameter from a form. I call an external method to generate the "isReady" result, but when I run this, the "isReady" result prints the code and not the desired result. This is pretty simple and I don't know what I'm missing.

```
function getWho(name, age) {

    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.isReady = youngOrOld;

    return [this.name, this.age, this.isReady];

}

function youngOrOld() {
    var result;
    var yourAge = this.age;

    switch(yourAge) {
        case (yourAge < 13) :
        result = "You're just a babe";
        break;
        case (yourAge >= 13 && yourAge < 18):
            result = "You're in your teens";
            break;
        case (yourAge >= 18 && yourAge < 50):
            result = "You are an adult";
            break;
        case (yourAge >= 50):
            result = "You are a senior";
            break;
        default:
            result = "";
    }

    return result;
}

function getAgeResult(n, a) {

    var myArr = getWho(n, a);

    var myName = myArr[0].valueOf();
    var myAge = myArr[1].valueOf();
    var myResult = myArr[2].valueOf();

    document.getElementById("myDiv2").innerHTML = "Hello " + myName + ", you are " + myAge + " old and " + myResult;
}
```

Here is the result:
Hello chris, you are 23 old and function youngOrOld() { var result; var yourAge = this.age; switch(yourAge) { case (yourAge < 13) : result = "You're just a babe"; break; case (yourAge >= 13 && yourAge < 18): result = "You're in your teens"; break; case (yourAge >= 18 && yourAge < 50): result = "You are an adult"; break; case (yourAge >= 50): result = "You are a senior"; break; default: result = ""; } return result; }

Comment: What about execute the function? `this.isReady = youngOrOld()` ?

Answer (score 1):

It's because youngOrOld is a function, and when it's added to string the interpreter call toString method that return the whole function code. You must execute function to get you're result.

This is the corrected code :

```
function getWho(name, age) {

    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.isReady = youngOrOld;
    //if you execute it now youngOrOld will not recognize this.age

    return [this.name, this.age, this.isReady()];

}
```